# Extracting Navigation Logic From Angular Components

Tags: angular

I have a number of Angular components all with routing setup so that there is a specific url for each one.  The requirement is that I need to navigate from one to the next in a series based on what data the user enters along the way.  Some of these components will be used multiple times at different stages along the way.

I could add the logic in each component to work out which is the next component to go to, but I feel like this logic should be extracted out into a separate class somewhere which can view all the data collected so far, but I can't work out the right way to do this.

Any suggestions?  Are there examples of this type of pattern anywhere?

Comment: Can you maybe provide a minimal example of which data the routing will be based on? My suggestion is to use the URL to keep track of the state in order to get a shareable and reloadable state if possible.

Comment: Data will be all kinds of things that are collected as we go through the flow, but I don't feel like all of the components should need to know about all of this data, they should just do their own data collection and return it to something which controls the flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what service are for.

Create a service that manage all of the data required for routing, and routes according to this data.

This way, the service becomes your single source of truth when it comes to routing, which is a good practice. For instance, if you have to change a route later on, you won't have to browse every file to update it, just the service.

**EDIT : an idea of the service**

```js
export class RoutingService {

  private data: any;

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  startDataConstruction(params: any) {
    this.data = params;
  }

  updateData(params: any) {
    if (!this.data) 
      throw new Error('please construct your data first');
    Object.assign(this.data, parems);
  } 

  dataRoute() {
    // Do your routing logic here then
    delete this.data;
  }

}
```

Comment: That's definitely the kind of thing I'm thinking of, but I can't quite work out what kind of functions would be on that service that the components would call.  Would there be a specific function for each "Continue" button in each component, for example, which the component would pass it's data to?

Comment: @fosbie you did not provide enough code or logic to let me answer, but I made a quick service example for you, feel free to look at it

Comment: So I assume I would call startDataConstruction at the start of the flow, then perhaps have a number of different updataData methods, so that each Continue button click would update the data that component had just collected, then call dataRoute to navigate to the next component.  Looks good, thanks for that

Comment: No problem, if it helped be sure to upvote it, and if it resolved yuor issue, be sure to mark it as resolved !